# About trigonometric test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We know that, if $b_k$ is monotone decreasing and $\lim b_k =0$, then $\sum b_k \sin kt $ is convergent for all $t\in R $.

IF we change the condition from $b_1 \geq b_2 \geq ....\geq 0$

to

$b_N+1 \geq b_N+2 \geq ....\geq 0$, i.e, $b_k$ is monotone decreasing after some $N$.

Does this test still hold ?

I my intuition is that it still holds.

Any hint?

Comment: Yes, because the asymptotic behaviour of a series  does not depend on the first $N$ terms, provided $N$ is fixed since Cauchy's criterion is the same if you modify the first $N$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \sin kt = \sum_{k=0}^N b_k \sin kt +\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty b_k \sin kt =  \sum_{k=0}^N b_k \sin kt + \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \sin ((N+1+k)kt)  $$
The first sum is a finit number and $a_k=b_{N+1+k}$

then you can use $\sin(a+b)= \sin a \cos b+ \sin b \cos a$ and the test shown below